# Position caret at start of line when clicking to the left of a line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 (and possibly older versions as well, I don't know), clicking immediately to the left of a line of code selects the line. I find this to be an incredibly annoying "feature" that makes it very difficult to position the caret at the start of the line, requiring very accurate cursor aim.

Is there a way to disable this such that clicking to the left of a line simply positions the caret at the start of the line?

[image]

Comment: I believe...double clikcing selects the line...and single click simply positions :o imo

Comment: @Rajaji It doesn't seem to. Single-clicking where the arrow is pointing in the screenshot above selects the whole line and onto the next line.